# I get the following error when I use an ExifInterface in Android API 29

Tags: java, android

I am using API 29 with version 3.5.3 of gradle.

The error is as follows:

```
ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
    java.io.IOException: Invalid byte order: 0
        at android.media.ExifInterface.readByteOrder(ExifInterface.java:3128)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.isOrfFormat(ExifInterface.java:2443)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.getMimeType(ExifInterface.java:2321)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1755)
        at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1449)
```

This is the code that generates the error:

```
public static byte[] compressImageToBytes(Uri imageUri, int quality, int height, int width, Context context, Bitmap.CompressFormat format) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ExifInterface exif;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 28) {
            InputStream image = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image);
            exif = new ExifInterface(image);
            image.close();
        }
        else {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            exif = new ExifInterface(getImageRealPathFromURI(context, imageUri));
        }

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        Bitmap compressed = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleBitmap(compressed, width, height);
        scaledBitmap = overlayBitmapToCenter(Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888), scaledBitmap);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledBitmap.compress(format, quality, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Could someone guide me on how to resolve this error, thanks.

Comment: Based on the error message, the image you are reading is either unsupported or corrupt.

Comment: I have tried various types of PNG, JPG images ... created by myself as downloaded